# Eslint: use only on rule from plugin

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to use a rule from an eslint plugin.
I want this to be the only rule to be used from that plugin. In my concrete case it's about eslint-plugin-import and the 'import/named' rule. How can I achieve this with the minimum amount of custom config?
In my eslintrc I have

```js
{
  extends: ['plugin:import/errors'],
  plugins: ['import'],
  rules: { 'import/named': 2 },
  // ... other settings
}
```

I know I could manually add `'import/no-unresolved': 0` and all the other rules from the plugin to the rules section but it would be nice to have an easier solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are extending rules from the plugin with the `extends` setting. Just skip that part. To have no predefined rules, just add the plugin to the `plugins` array and define the rule(s) by yourself:

```
{
  plugins: ['import'],
  rules: { 'import/named': 2 },
  // ... other settings
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I think this is poorly documented in the eslint docs